# Cassandra Data Model design for vnodes enabled cluster?

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling, cql

I have recently started working with Cassandra. We have cassandra cluster which is using DSE 4.0 version and has VNODES enabled. We have a tables like this -

Below is my first table -

```
CREATE TABLE customers (
  customer_id int PRIMARY KEY,
  last_modified_date timeuuid,
  customer_value text
)
```

Read query pattern is like this on above table as of now since we need to get everything from above table and load it into our application memory every x minutes.

```
select customer_id, customer_value from datakeyspace.customers;
```

We have second table like this -

```
CREATE TABLE client_data (
  client_name text PRIMARY KEY,
  client_id text,
  creation_date timestamp,
  is_valid int,
  last_modified_date timestamp
)

CREATE INDEX idx_is_valid_clnt_data ON client_data (is_valid);
```

Right now in the above table, we have 500 records and all those records has "is_valid" column value set as 1. And the read query pattern is like this on above table as of now since we need to get everything from above table and load it into our application memory every x minutes so the below query will return me all 500 records since everything has is_valid set to 1.

```
select client_name, client_id from  datakeyspace.client_data where is_valid=1;
```

Since our cluster is VNODES enabled so my above query pattern is not efficient at all and it is taking lot of time to get the data from Cassandra. It takes around 50 seconds to get the data from cqlsh client. We are reading from these table with consistency level QUORUM.

Is there any possibility of improving our data model by using wide rows concept or anything else?

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What makes you think using vnodes is inefficient?

Comment: since then it will query each vnodes to get the data. Vnodes is only useful for operational perspective and even datastax consultant also told us same thing so we are working on re-designing the tables.

Comment: The actual issue here is using Secondary indexes, the vnodes is kinda ancillary

Comment: @RussS I see. Do you think our data model design looks good? Or is there any way to improve it?

Comment: An index on `is_valid` will perform poorly because it has such low cardinality.  It doesn't make sense to index fields that only have a few possible values.  As for the right way, you should look at Patrick McFadin's article on modeling time series data: http://planetcassandra.org/blog/getting-started-with-time-series-data-modeling/

Comment: And as far as VNodes go, I do see two JIRA tickets (4858, 5161) about VNodes performing poorly with secondary indexes.  However, they are both old and have since been resolved.  Restrictions about VNode usage involving Solr and Hadoop clusters exist.  But I have not heard or read anything to substantiate that "Vnodes is only useful for operational perspective."  Everyone I've asked at DataStax has emphatically supported the use of VNodes.